# java.io.IOException error=2, No such file or directory

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm new to Android and being trying to run some vague program called "HelloWorld" which I have written on Rust and output the result into UI. Here is the code which was supposed to do that

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import java.io.File
import java.io.IOException
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val buttonRun = findViewById<Button>(R.id.Run)
        val output = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.output)



        buttonRun.setOnClickListener {
            //val someText = "Hello World!"
            val rust = File ("home/querens/Documents/Android/TESTapp/app/src/main/rust")
            val rustResult = "./HelloWorld".runCommand(rust)
            output.text = rustResult
        }
    }
}

fun String.runCommand(workingDir: File): String? {
    try {
        val parts = this.split("\\s".toRegex())
        val proc = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            ProcessBuilder(*parts.toTypedArray())
                    .directory(workingDir)
                    .redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.PIPE)
                    .redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.PIPE)
                    .start()
        } else TODO("VERSION.SDK_INT < O")

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            proc.waitFor(60, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        }
        return proc.inputStream.bufferedReader().readText()
    } catch(e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        return null
    }
}
```

I get no other errors so I assume that the code migh be fine, but I'm not 100% sure. The only error I get is this one. I've read a lot of posts with this error but I couldn't implement any solution this far.

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "./HelloWorld" (in directory "home/querens/Documents/Android/TESTapp/app/src/main/rust"): error=2, No such file or directory

Comment: Well the directory home does not exist on an Android device. It looks as if you tried to use a directory of your development pc.

Comment: @blackapps that's right. Can I do that? I've emulated the device... But yeah, feels wrong. Shall I move this exec to my emulated device somehow first?